# Winding number of a surjective map

Tags: complex-analysis, winding-number

> Consider a map $\gamma: [0,T] \rightarrow [0,1] \times [0,1]$ such that is continous and surjective. Compute the winding number of $\gamma$ in $a$ ($ind(\gamma,a)$), where $a \notin Im(\gamma)$.

I've justed started studying winding numbers where comes to me that problem. I do know how to compute it using integrals and topological ways, however, I do not know how to do it since $\gamma$ is no explicited given.

Comment: It's not clear what $a$ is.  Is this exactly what is written in the problem?  [My guess is $a \in \mathbb{R}^2\setminus ([0,1]^2)$ but this isn't specified at all]

Comment: @BrianMoehring that's exactly how it is written. I am considering that $a$ is a point in the complex plane

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the intent is for $a \in \mathbb{R}^2 \setminus ([0,1]^2)$, then we can draw a line through $a$ such that the image of $\gamma$ lies entirely in one of the two open half-planes.

This implies the angle on $\gamma$ about $a$ lies entirely in some $(\theta, \theta+\pi)$ for some $\theta$ (which we can set to $\theta = 0$ or $\theta = -\pi/2$ if we really want).  This allows us to conclude the winding number for the *closed* curve $\gamma$ is $0$.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: The winding number should be zero.  If $\gamma$ is surjective, then $a\notin\rm{im}\gamma\implies a$ is outside of $\gamma$.

There's a theorem that when $a$ is in the unbounded part of $\Bbb C\setminus\rm{im}\gamma$ the index is zero.

(Intuitively, we have a space filling curve, and there's no way for it to wrap around a point without hitting it.)

Comment: I'm a bit curious here.  Which integral are you talking about?  (the ones I know about require more regularity in the path than this $\gamma$ has)

Comment: @BrianMoehring good point.  I may have gotten ahead of myself.